# How can i use same regex for two different strings?

Tags: php, regex, string

hi have string,

```
$rt="Ability: B,Session: Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM),Time: 9:30am,karthi";

$rt="Ability: B,Session: Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM),Time: 9:30pm,karthi";
```

i used below regex for remove text from last comma(,).

```
$it_nme = preg_replace('/(?<=pm,)\S*/is', '', $rt);
```

it is worked for second string (because before comma have 'pm' text). for second one before comma we have string 'am'.

for both how can i write single regex?

Comment: As an aside: You really should learn at least the basics of regular expressions before using them in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(?<=[ap]m,)\S*/is', '', $rt)
```

Comment: it replaces  Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM) form here in string. but i need lowercase letter "pm".

Comment: @Ravichandran It should not replace the `PM` because the regex requires a `,` after the `pm`. To make the regex case-sensitive, remove the `i` modifier at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex `OR` like so:

```
$it_nme = preg_replace('/(?<=(pm|am),)\S*/is', '', $rt);
```